# MSTest cannot find the assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I was using MSTest

and i use command mstest /testsettings:local.Testsetting /testcontainer:folder\obj\Debug\test.dll

and this is the output,

> Run has the following issue(s):
>   Warning: Test Run deployment issue:
>   The assembly or module
>   'Microsoft.Practices. Prism' directly
>   or indirectly referenced by the test
>   container 'test.dll' was not found.
>   Warning: Test Run deployment issue:
>   The assembly or module
>   'Project.Common.dll' directly or
>   indirectly referenced by the test
>   container 'test.dll' was not found.
>   Warning: Test Run deployment issue:
>   The assembly or module
>   'Project.Infrastructure.dll' directly
>   or indirectly referenced by the test
>   container 'test.dll' was not found.
>   Warning: Test Run deployment issue:
>   The assembly or module
>   'Microsoft.Practices. Prism' directly
>   or indirectly referenced by the test
>   container 'test.dll' was not found.

What can i do so MSTest can run well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the Prism file in the GAC of your build server.

Answer (score 3):

All assemblies that are not used directly in test will not be copied to test folder. Therefor, those test methods should be decorated with attribute like:

```
[DeploymentItem("Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll")]
```

This solves the problem without adding the assembly to the GAC.

Comment: I am getting a similar error, and the project is buiding in Jenkins. How to use your solution in Jenkins? Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'zlib.net' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'd:\alm_jenprodslave_1\workspace\total fund\alm\otpp.pivot.core\otpp.pivot.core.model.test\bin\debug\otpp.pivot.core.model.test.dll' was not found.

Comment: Does this approach (using just the name) definitely work when the assembly IS NOT in the GAC? I am having issues and have had to put the full file path instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The DeploymentItem is a way to fix this.  However, DeploymentItem is a little fragile.

Here is how I fixed it.

The "current directory" has to line up with the DeploymentItem.  The best compromise I found would be to set the current directory to where the .sln file is.

Here is my folder structure.

```
C:\SomeRootFolder\
C:\SomeRootFolder\MySolution.sln
C:\SomeRootFolder\packages\
C:\SomeRootFolder\packages\MyNugetPackage.1.2.3.4\lib\net45\SomeThirdPartyDll.dll
C:\SomeRootFolder\MyTestProject\MyTestProject.csproj
C:\SomeRootFolder\MyTestProject\MyTestClass.cs
```

MyTestClass.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    /* The DeploymentItem item below is for error ::: Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'SomeDll' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'C:\SomeRootFolder\MyTestProject\bin\debug\MyTestProject.dll' was not found. */
    /* There must be a CD (to the .sln folder) command... before the MsTest.exe command is executed */
    [DeploymentItem(@".\packages\MyNugetPackage.1.2.3.4\lib\net45\SomeDll.dll")]
    public void MyTest()
    {
    }
}
```

The "trick" is to do a CD (change directory) to the folder that houses the .sln.

```
REM Now the normal restore,build lines
nuget.exe restore "C:\SomeRootFolder\MySolution.sln"
REM the above nuget restore would create "C:\SomeRootFolder\packages\MyNugetPackage.1.2.3.4\lib\net45\SomeThirdPartyDll.dll"
MSBuild.exe "C:\SomeRootFolder\MySolution.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug;FavoriteFood=Popeyes /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MySolution.Debug.Build.log
REM (the below line is the trick to line up the 'current folder' with the relative path of the DeploymentItem)
cd "C:\SomeRootFolder\"
REM now the below will work without the annoying message, note that C:\SomeRootFolder\MyTestProject\bin\Debug\SomeThirdPartyDll.dll exists
MsTest.exe /testcontainer:"C:\SomeRootFolder\MyTestProject\bin\Debug\MyTestProject.dll" /resultsfile:MyTestProject.Dll.Results.trx
```

Now because the "current directory" (the result of the CD) is at "C:\SomeRootFolder\", the DeploymentItem relative path works correctly.

Jimminy Crickets.......that is a little nutsy.

Note, the Paul Taylor answer here

[Running MsTest from the command line with a custom assembly base directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907884/running-mstest-from-the-command-line-with-a-custom-assembly-base-directory)

did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way.
Just add

```
 string value = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

to your code (at the start point of your test method)
Add a breakpoint to the newly added code and check what is the path of `value` variable.

continue the test process and after everything get success navigate to the folder of `values` variable.

You might see all the dlls inside the folder.
Just copy them and past ware ever you want and execute the project dll using mstest command line tool.

```
set mstestPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"

%mstestpath%\mstest /testcontainer:CodedUITestProject1.dll
```