# run mstest from cmd using testcontainer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I am trying to run MSTest from command prompt and have added the folder that contains `MSTest.exe` in path variable. I have tried

`MSTest /testcontainer: test.dll`  from the folder where `test.dll` reside

also tried giving full path

`MSTest /testcontainer: C:\..\..\bin\Debug\test.dll` but received

`Invalid switch "test.dll"`
`Invalid switch "c"` respectively

I tried to run without adding `MSTest.exe` to path i.e. from the folder where `MSTest.exe` resides, but similar result. How do I make MSTest work from cmd? Is it missing something obvious?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907884/running-mstest-from-the-command-line-with-a-custom-assembly-base-directory) is a similar question asked but my solution does not have any `.testrunconfig` file as stated there. Neither  could I locate a file in my solution where `applicationBaseDirectory` is mentioned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to run test using `vstest.console.exe` instead of `MSTest` from command prompt  from folder where `Tests.dll` is located. Mine is located at  `\bin\Debug` in project folder.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" Tests.dll`